Is this HVAC reducing plenum system designed correctly?
I am redoing my duct work for my home. I have a 3 ton, 1200 CFM central air system. It is currently a undersized "octopus" system. This is what I've landed on for a reducing plenum design. Looking for feedback before I go getting this fabricated. I've done load calcs and such to figure out room CFM needs, I'm just unsure of the actual reducing plenum design. I read somewhere that 8" rectangular duct is the standard, but I'm not married to it.
I did 2 foot spacing between takeoffs and the trunk ends. I reduced after about 400 CFM. I intend to have dampers on all takeoffs.

